# how to add that classname(to refer plugin) to the checkboxes while creating dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with JavaScript and Jquery Application. In that, I have created a checkbox dynamically by using the following codings...`

//this function called from a for loop and will get name, j values from XML and create checkbox with that name...

```
function append(name,j)       
         {                
            var cb = document.createElement( "input" );
            cb.type = "checkbox";
            cb.id = "id";
            cb.value = "test";
            cb.checked = false;
            cb.className='checkbox_container';
            var text = document.createTextNode( name );
            document.getElementById( 'append' ).appendChild( cb ); 
            document.getElementById( 'append' ).appendChild( text );
     }
```

Also, this created checkbox will display in DiV below,

```
<div class="checkbox_container" id="append">      </div>
```

Here Class=checkbox_container is used for serchbox plugin....

I have tried the above method using static checkboxes like ...

```
<div class="checkbox_container"><img src="11.jpeg" width="30" height="30">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" /><span>Nandha</span></div>
        <div class="checkbox_container"><img src="12.jpeg" width="30" height="30">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" /><span>Senthil</span></div>
```

If i create these check box statically, the checkbox_container class refers plugin and display the suggestions in the search box.....but if i create dynamic chack box..it is not display suggestions...

My question is , how to add that classname(to refer plugin) to the checkboxes while creating dynamically????....
please help me...

Comment: What you've got should work.  What makes you think it doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the code to initialise the plugin after the checkboxes are created.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mozilla then you should use `cb.class` instead of `cb.className`.